# Why "found in the string" doesn't work correct in php?

Tags: php, string

I need to find special templates in strings. One of this strings is:

```
@if($fabric->id == $product->fabric_id)<br />\r
```

When I try to check `@if` in string with php function **strpos**, it gives me `false`. Link to sandbox:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f54c3a1c0124086833deccf4fbcb5e07b656fa93

But it works correctly when the string has a space before '@if'. Why?
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55b2046ba7f4e1fdc88cf5fd4113e681b7dd4a75

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns an index of the string that you search. In first case it is 0 (zero), since `@if` is at the very beginning. When there is a space before it, the position is 1 (one). What confuses you is that 0 (zero) is also interpreted as `false` by PHP in conditional statements, while 1 (one) is interpreted as `true`.

If you want to make sure that the string was not found at all, not even at zero position, you need to use strict comparison operators:

```
if (strpos($str, '@if') === false) { echo 'Not found'; }
```

Comment: As said in [strpos documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), you should use `===` operator to check if strpos return really false or not.